# How can I change the bottom color of my drawer?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer

I have created my drawer. I have put the list tiles in a container and set the color of my container to white but the bottom of drawer still shows black. The widget is put in a separate class. I want the whole drawer to white except the drawer header which is in yellow. How can I solve it.
Here is code snippet:
[image]
class NavigationDrawerWidget extends StatelessWidget {

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
         children: <Widget>[
           Container(
             width: double.infinity,
             padding: EdgeInsets.only(
               top: 50,
               bottom: 50,
             ),
             color: Colors.yellow,
             child: Center(
               child: Column(
                 children: [
                   Container(
                     width: 100,
                     height: 100,
                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                       shape: BoxShape.circle,
                       image: DecorationImage(
                           image: AssetImage('images/profile.png'),
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                   SizedBox(
                     height: 20,
                   ),
                   Text(
                     'Usama Tahir',
                     style: TextStyle(
                       color: Colors.black,
                     ),
                   )
                 ],
               ),
             ),
           ),
           Container(
             // color: Colors.white,
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
               color: Colors.white,
             ),
             child: Column(
               children: [
                 ListTile(
                   leading: Icon(
                       Icons.person,
                     color: Colors.black,
                   ),
                   title: Text(
                     'Profile',
                     style: TextStyle(
                       color: Colors.black,
                     ),
                   ),
                   onTap: null,
                 ),
                 ListTile(
                   leading: Icon(
                     Icons.account_balance_outlined,
                     color: Colors.black,
                   ),
                   title: Text(
                     'Tansaction History',
                     style: TextStyle(
                       color: Colors.black,
                     ),
                   ),
                   onTap: null,
                 ),
                 ListTile(
                   leading: Icon(
                       Icons.password_outlined,
                     color: Colors.black,
                   ),
                   title: Text(
                     'Change Password',
                     style: TextStyle(
                       color: Colors.black,
                     ),
                   ),
                   onTap: null,
                 ),
                 ListTile(
                   leading: Icon(
                       Icons.settings_accessibility_outlined,
                     color: Colors.black,
                   ),
                   title: Text(
                     'Profile',
                     style: TextStyle(
                       color: Colors.black,
                     ),
                   ),
                   onTap: null,
                 ),
             

Expanded(
               child: Column(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                 children: [
                   ListTile(
                     leading: Icon(
                         Icons.login_outlined,
                       color: Colors.black,
                     ),
                     title: Text(
                       'Logout',
                       style: TextStyle(
                         color: Colors.black,
                       ),
                     ),
                     onTap: () {
                       Navigator.push(context,
                           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => `WelcomeScreen()));`
                     },
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
             ),
               ],
             ),

           ),

         ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have turned on the dark mode of your phone. If the dark mode is on, turn it off, run the app and check the output

Comment: Can you help me in moving Logout text at the bottom of the drawer? I have wrapped it with align and then alignment: bottom.centre, but still no effect.

Comment: check my updated answer to set logout text at the bottom and please select and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `backgroundColor: Colors.white` property in `Drawer` widget and you are all set to go.

Comment: Can you help me in moving Logout text at the bottom of the drawer? I have wrapped it with align and then alignment: bottom.centre, but still no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Drawer(backgroundColor: Colors.white,
```

try this to make logout to set at the bottom.

```
Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 50,
                bottom: 50,
              ),
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      // decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      //   shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      //   image: DecorationImage(
                      //     image: AssetImage('images/profile.png'),
                      //   ),
                      // ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Usama Tahir',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              // color: Colors.white,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      'Profile',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: null,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.account_balance_outlined,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      'Tansaction History',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: null,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.password_outlined,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      'Change Password',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: null,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.settings_accessibility_outlined,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      'Profile',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: null,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.login_outlined,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      'Logout',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: null,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Comment: Can you help me in moving Logout text at the bottom of the drawer? I have wrapped it with align and then alignment: bottom.centre, but still no effect.

Comment: check my updated answer to set logout text at the bottom and please select and upvote.

Comment: I have edited the solution with the error that came after making the changes you suggested. Kindly check

Comment: Don't use sizedbox. Check my code which wrapped ListTile with Expanded and column

Comment: I have used that, it shows the above error

Comment: Above means. What error?

Comment: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent.

Comment: Update the question with the updated code

Comment: I have updated the code, you may check.

Comment: I think you have misplaced the code. Don't put the code inside with other listtiles.  Make sure that code (expanded) directly inside the first column or  just copy paste the above code and check.

Comment: Yes, it worked, but it took it to the very end of the drawer, I used the sizedBox after the logout text to lift it little bit from the bottom. Is it the right approach? And Thankyou for the previous difficulties. Really appreciated.

Comment: Glad it worked. I don't know that  it's a right approach or not. But I would do the same if that's in my case. Sometimes Padding will also used.